# do I need to fill with spackle or can I paint directly

Tags: painting, paint, spackling-paste

I have the corner of my wall chipped a little

[image]

Do I need to fill this with spackle or can I paint directly?

Also, will spackle absorb moisture and cause problems this way?

This is in the bathroom.

(I tried to fill in with spackle but it fell out. It turned out to be super hard to fill in because it's on the corner).

So again, my questions are:

1. Can I touch up with paint directly?
2. Does spackle in the bathroom cause problems due to absorbing moisture?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would add some primer and then just paint. If you use a semi-gloss or high gloss enamel, you shouldn't have any major problems with the metal.

You can always try to spackle this, but you'll run into two problems

1. It's a corner
2. It's metal underneath

Comment: Do I need to scrape off loose paint or I can just paint as is?

Comment: Scraping isn't necessary. You won't notice after the painting. Only scrape if it's actively peeling

Comment: I'm curious how this answer is not a duplicate of the one I posted, other than to be shorter and less comprehensive.

Comment: @fred_dot_u Less comprehensive? There's no need for abrasion or acetone with standard paint. Corners get chipped all the time. There's no need for either step. If you paint it without any filling you'd be hard pressed to spot the difference.

Comment: Hey @Machavity. I went to the paint shop and they told me to use a "metal paint" for this. Is that different from semi/high gloss enamel?
Also, if it's different, then will semi/high gloss enamel stick to the metal?

Comment: I was told to use this paint: http://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/tremclad-rust-paint-1g-0489325p.html#srp (the container was about 250 ml)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using anything except a normal latex paint. I mean, I just helped my wife paint a brand new room, with standard metal trim around the windows, and we used nothing but normal paint. Your wall isn't made out of metal so it's odd that they suggested something like that.

Comment: Thanks @Machavity. I think so too. They were probably thinking that since the bead is metal then I should use metal paint.
Also you know what, I'll try patching it with drywall compound first (before applying the paint) instead of spackling. I had to patch up a wall in the garage and used drywall compound, I like that material 1000X more than spackle.

Answer (score 1):

The corner of your wall may be "protected" with corner bead, a metal strip that is bonded to the wallboard and provides impact resistance. If you can see the metal surface in the chip, it may be that you need to prepare the surface to take the paint you use to cover it. Using a paint that is also a primer will help in that regard.

Abrade the surface as well as you can, perhaps extending to the paint around the chip. Ensure that the surface is clean, using an appropriate solvent. Acetone or similar material that will not damage the surrounding area, or even rubbing alcohol may serve the purpose.

If you use a paint that includes a primer and comes in a spray can, mask off the area around the chip to avoid overspray, or spray some into a container and apply with a small brush.

It's difficult to determine the depth of the chip. If too deep to simply paint over, you would still want to prepare the surface and use something like auto body filler putty (or bondo!) to get a good bond to the underlying surface. Any filler would have to be sanded to have a smooth surface for the paint, of course.

Comment: Damn in man. Why isn't there a damn course in school for this. lol
So I need to abrade the surface? And clean it with acetone?!!

Comment: Also, when you say, apply it with a small brush, you mean apply it only into the chip itself? Or do I paint the chip and around it a little too in order to blend the touch up into the existing paint?

Comment: I suggested a small brush in order to avoid spreading too much over the surrounding area. You'd want to match colors as much as possible, of course, but if you limit it to the chip alone, you would not notice much difference. The chip is so small that it might be difficult to abrade the metal surface, while the primer or primer/paint combination would chemically attach to the metal. I think the education I have is the school of hard knocks. Don't be afraid to make mistakes, but learn from them too.